# Finding multiple instances of patterns within a pattern using RegExp

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I'm trying to find several text matches using RegExp, all of them showing up within a pattern.
For example:
Suppose I have a div tag which contains a "text array":

```
<div class="example" data-uris="[a][b][c]" data-title=".../>
```

What I'm trying to do using regexp, is to find 3 groups: a, b and c.
All of them of course are following a certain div, and percede quotes and other attributes, which show up only once in the string, and every group is contained within square brackets, repeatedly.
However, building a regexp will only supply the first group: a.

Any ideas?

Comment: provide inputs and expected outputs

Comment: I did. Consider my given div.
For that, I'd like to find a, b and c (they could be longer than a single character, but this example will do fine)

Comment: using jquery or only js?

Comment: Just a regular expression (The actual implementation will be in C#, but the regular expression conventions are similar to javascript for that matter)

Comment: in js or jquery you could directly access the value of data-uris in a string, and then you could perform your further operations

Comment: I've already stated this must be done using a regular expression without further coding

Comment: Please don't do us "favors" by shortening the problem. Put the exact thing being searched for, or at least the exact structure. __Regex is very literal__--if you're not searching for an `a`, then don't show us an `a`. Show us what you intend to find.

Comment: Regex is surely literal, and can help me find the bracketed data should it be 'a' or anything else.
I've got an html, and I'm trying to extract those urls ('a','b','c') within the brackets, wrapped by a cetain div class.

Answer (score 0):

Here is extended solution with regexp `exec` method:

```
<div class="example" data-uris="[abc][bde][cfg]" data-title=""></div>
```

---

```
var div = document.getElementsByClassName('example')[0],
    uris = div.getAttribute('data-uris'), 
    match,
    matches = [],
    pattern = /\[([a-z]+)+?\]+/g;

while((match = pattern.exec(uris)) != null){
   matches.push(match[1]);
}
console.log(matches);
// output: Array [ "abc", "bde", "cfg" ]
```

The code snippet:

```js
var div = document.getElementsByClassName('example')[0],
    uris = div.getAttribute('data-uris'), 
    match,
    matches = [],
    pattern = /\[([a-z]+)+?\]+/g;
    
while((match = pattern.exec(uris)) != null){
   matches.push(match[1]);
}
console.log(matches);
```

```html
<div class="example" data-uris="[abc][bde][cfg]" data-title=""></div>
```

Comment: I need to use a single RegEx without being able to modify/add code,
so I could ensure the div and its attribute, then get several bracketed matches within

Comment: @ShlomiUziel, what if there will be 50 divs with class `example`?  Which one of them should be selected? It seems that you are going to 'invent' some redundant logic which could be match simpler.

Comment: Then I want them all

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the question correctly, this may be the start of what you are looking for:

```
// iteration through elements
var elements = window.document.all;
for (var i = 0, l = elements.length; i < l; i++) {
    if (elements[i].localName === 'div') {
        console.log(elements[i].outerHTML.match(/\[a\]\[b\]\[c\]/));
    }
}
// match on the document's text
var html = window.document.documentElement.innerHTML;
console.log(html.match(/\[a\]\[b\]\[c\]/));
```

Comment: I need to apply a regex on the full HTML text, without applying any other methods (I.e. without traversing the DOM element tree using code)

Comment: You can access that via `window.document.documentElement.innerHTML`, I'll up the example.

Comment: Was curious, did this help you achieve what you were trying to do @ShlomiUziel ?

Comment: Your approach helped me to understand that trying to process html (which might as well be irregular) is far easier by extracting the element then processing the desired string result using regex (My implementation used XPath).
In that particular case, the regexp already matched the perceding div attribute, and thats why I got the first instance.

Comment: @ShlomiUziel nice! most, excellent conclusions, sir. I would concur with your observations, i.e. it is far easier, and arguably more efficient, to extract the element in question as needed, utilizing other selection methods. Experiential realizations that are often difficult to communicate in small, textual blurbs, and even if one is able to find the correct words, I find that in most instances, reactions to such are subject to the idiom, "you can lead a horse to water, but you can't make it drink." ;) Thanks for sharing your findings and feedback. Take care.